# SMS group APP Inventor2

Tags: list, sms, app-inventor

I made an APP with APP Inventor2 that sends SMS with latitude and longitude, but I can not make a schedule to send SMS for two numbers. Anything I try just sends to the first number I signed up. I have tested various possibilities and no longer know how else to solve.

Screenshot of code blocks used:

[image: Code blocks from APP Inventor 2]

Comment: _I have tested various possibilities_ - Please include specifics of what you have tried so far in your question so people know what isn't working.

Comment: You may also want to [edit] your question add a note that APP Inventor does not create text code, just graphic code blocks. (I edited your image into the question but I can't just create content and add it to your post.)

Comment: Use **Do it** to debug your blocks, see also tip 4 here [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php). See also this similar [example](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/HyitZbwMJOA/2hYC_Z3K1tQJ)

Comment: Hi folks, I managed to  actually was doing wrong now with these blocks the app sends an SMS to each number according to the amount of times I have determined.

Anyway thanks!